# Selenium verify if an element is a child of another in Java

Tags: java, html, selenium, dom

I have a series of nested elements in a page that I'm trying to navigate. The html below is a simplified version:

```html
<div>
  <h1 id="This is an id">The header is an identifier</h1>
  <table>
      <tr></tr>
      <tr>
         <ul>
           <li>
             <a>
               <span>This my target</span>
  </table>
</div>
        
        <h1>Also text</h1>
        <a>
        <span>This target has the same text<span>
```

The structure of the top div can very dramatically. I am trying to find an elements using xpath and text contains. However, I am having trouble verifying that the target is indeed the one inside the proper div. If there a way to scale back up the dom tree somehow if I don't know the exact layout of it every time?

Comment: You need to identify the div? or the element with the text?

Comment: I'm scanning the page to look for text and I need to make sure the text I find is from the div not outside of it. The issue is that the dom layout will change at run time so I wont know in advanced how far down the span is within that div.

Comment: How do you know which `div` is the right one?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `>` operation with CSS selector.

Example: to access `"This my target"`, you use 
`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li>a>span"));`

Answer (score 0):

For checking an text inside a div you could compose an path like:

```
//div//*[contains(text(), 'my text')]
```

If you need to check inside a specific div then you should identify the div first.

For example if the div has an attribute like `class="my_class"` then use:

```
//div[@class='my_class']//*[contains(text(), 'my text')]
```

You can find more path examples on [w3schools xpath syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp)

Comment: Does the * syntax work if I don't know how far down in the dive the [contains(text(), 'text')] is?

Comment: * selects any tag, // dives as down as possible